# "Unknown Error" while creating API spec in Swagger

Tags: node.js, swagger

Hi I'm creating a Sample API Spec using swagger as below :

I keep getting "Unknown Error on "Items:"  line

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: Todo API
# during dev, should point to your local machine
host: localhost:10010
# basePath prefixes all resource paths 
basePath: /
# 
schemes:
  # tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
# format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
consumes:
  - application/json
# format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /:
   get:
      description: "this endpoint returns list of todo events"
      operationId: "GetAllTodos"
      parameters:  []
      responses:
        200:
          description: "an array of all the present todos"
          schema:
              type: "array"
              items: 
                $ref: "#definitions/Todo"
      x-swagger-router-controller: "GetAllTodos"
  /swagger:
    x-swagger-pipe: swagger_raw
# complex objects have schema definitions
definitions:
 Todo:
  type: "object"
  properties: 
    todo_id:
      type: "integer"
      description: "id of the todo event"
    todo:
      type: "string"
      description: "The todo item"
    datecreated:
      type: "string"
      format: "date-time"
      description: "timestamp when the todo event was created"
    author:
      type: "string"
      description: "owner of the todo event"
    duedate:
      type: "string"
      format: "date-time"
      description: "time by when the todo event should be completed"
    completed:
      type: "boolean"
      description: "status of todo completion"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$ref: "#definitions/Todo"
```

to

```
$ref: "#/definitions/Todo"
```

Note the `/` after `#`.

Also, you are using an old version of Swagger Editor (2.x), which is no longer maintained. Consider using the latest version at http://editor.swagger.io.

Comment: I downloaded the one from npm using **npm install -g swagger**

Comment: it solved my problem but when I'm trying to send request from UI i'm getting **ERROR Server not found or an error occurred**

Comment: @kushal please [ask a new question](/questions/ask) about that.

Comment: I've raised a new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831618/error-server-not-found-or-an-error-occurred-while-using-swagger-spec-post-meth